# Posabsolute jQuery Validation engine in jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a legacy application whereby I have a couple of jQuery dialogs which have input elements on them.  I am using Posabsolute jQuery validation engine for these and it used to work fine, i.e. the validation messages used to bubble and show correctly in the dialog.

However, I had to upgrade the validation engine version and now they changed a bit the positioning of the validation message.  Whereas before the validation message was in the  tag, now the message shifted next to the input field which to a certain point makes sense.  However, this change has messed up all my validation messages as now they are showing inline instead of absolute positioning and showing nicely over the dialog.

Example:
The validation message below shows underneath the dialog title bar
[image]

Other validation messages are pushing the content and introducing vertical & horizontal scrolling in the dialog.

Using CSS and changing the z-index might be an issue due to the complexity of the application, so I was wondering whether someone managed to find a different approach.  Unfortunately, rolling back to an earlier version of the validation engine is not desirable :/

**EDIT** - adding sample code:
HTML:

```
<button id="opener">Open</button>
  <div id="dialog-message" title="Test Validation">
     <form id="validation">
       Email: <input value="" class="validate[required, custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
     </form>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            if ($("#validation").validationEngine('validate')){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "open" );
  $("#validation").validationEngine();
});
```

Link to jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/5616/  
If you click on the open button you can see that that validation bubble is hidden underneath the dialog header.

Comment: There has to be some code so that we can see what's happening..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  sample code added

Comment: Your fiddle not working. See the console for more detail. TypeError: $(...).validationEngine is not a function